# CLI/C++ function overload

Tags: c++-cli

I am currently writing a wrapper for a native C++ class in CLI/C++. I am on a little `GamePacket` class at the moment. Consider the following class:

```
public ref class GamePacket
{
public:
    GamePacket();
    ~GamePacket();

    generic<typename T>
    where T : System::ValueType
    void Write(T value)
    {
        this->bw->Write(value);
    }
};
```

I want that I'm able to call the function as following in C#, using my Wrapper:

`Packet.Write<Int32>(1234);
Packet.Write<byte>(1);`

However, I can't compile my wrapper. Error:

`Error  1   error C2664: 'void System::IO::BinaryWriter::Write(System::String ^)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'T' to 'bool'`

I don't understand this error, where does the `System::String^` comes from. I'm seeing a lot of overloads of the `Write()` method, does CLI/C++ not call the correct one, and if so, how can I make it call the correct one?

Reference MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates and generics don't work the same.

With templates, the code gets recompiled for each set of parameters, and the results can be pretty different (different local variable types, different function overloads selected).  Specialization makes this *really* powerful.

With generics, the code only gets compiled once, and the overload resolution is done without actually knowing the final parameters.  So when you call `Write(value)`, the only things the compiler knows is that

- `value` can be converted to `Object^`, because everything can
- `value` derives from `ValueType`, because your constraint tells it

Unfortunately, using just that information, the compiler can't find an overload of `Write` that can be used.

It seems like you expected it to use `Write(bool)` when `T` is `bool`, `Write(int)` when `T` is `int`, and so on.  Templates would work like that.  Generics don't.

Your options are:

- a dozen different copies of your method, each of which has a fixed argument type that can be used to select the right overload of `BinaryWrite::Write`
- find the overload yourself using reflection, make a delegate matching the right overload, and call it
- use expression trees or the dynamic language runtime to find and make a delegate matching the right overload, and then you call it

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Can I not use my generic, and then put inside something such as: `if(value->GetType() == __typeof(float)) { this->bw->Write((float)value); }` (I don't know the correct syntax)?

Comment: @hresult: You could, but that's just as much work as multiple overloads, and loses type checking (if the argument type isn't on your list, you won't find out until runtime)  BTW the syntax would be `if (T::typeid == float::typeid)`